# C# How to add value to ViewModel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I'll try explaining what I'm trying to do - Currently I have a model for each table I'm using, and a ViewModel to contain only a part of the table content .

I also add an extra property or two to the ModelView, that comes from another table. My question is, how do I assign the value(I have a function that bring me that property) to the viewModel object ?

The ViewModel :

```
public class StreetViewModel
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; } // THIS IS THE EXTRA PROPERTY
}
```

My Controller action to assign the object :

```
public IActionResult GetStreetByName(string streetName)
{
        var results = _repository.GetStreetByName(streetName); //Return a list of object of type Street
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<StreetViewModel>>(results)); // convert Street object to STREETVIEWMODEL object and return it.
}
```

My `GetStreetByName` method:

```
public IEnumerable<Street> GetStreetByName(string streetName)
{
    return _context.Street.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(streetName)).ToList();
}
```

This method will return a list of object type `Street` for me, in each one I have `CityId` , and I want to also select the `CityName` which appears only in the `City` table.

I also have a method to get city object by an ID:

```
public City GetCityNameById(int cityId)
{
    return _context.City.Where(t => t.Id == cityId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Where and how can I assign a cityName to each record of `Street` ?

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper?

Comment: Yes I am @FelipeOriani

Comment: You should use ProjectTo, not Map. The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `AutoMapper`, by native convention on this tool you can nagivate on the properties using the property name on the `TDestionation`, for sample. Let's supose you have these entities:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Street 
{
   public City City { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you define a property on the `StreetViewModel` called `CityName`, the AutoMapper will look for a property called `CityName` on your `TSource` and it will not be found. Then, it will try to look at `City` and it will be found and after a property called `Name`. It is a convetion by autoMapper using the case of the letters on the property name, so, pay attention on it.

### AutoMapper - custom mapping

In the other hand, you can configure it on the mapping. For sample:

```
config.CreateMap<Street, StreetViewModel>()
   .ForMember(t => t.CityName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.City.Name));
```

### Important - SELECT N+1 problem

Remember to fetch the `City` property when you hit the query on the database using the `ORM` (Entity Framework or NHibernate) to avoid the lazy loading. If you have many records on the `Street` result set, it will cause [`SELECT N+1` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue). With `Entity Framework` you can use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) and in `NHibernate` you can use [`Fetch`](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2014/07/04/nhibernate-fetch-strategies.aspx).

Comment: Question - My `GetStreetByName` method is selecting a list of streets. Will the Automapper automatically attach each of them to the correct City by `CityId` ? Or how does this attachment occurs (My DB has relations but my Project not, I just created classes based on my DB and didn't created them one from another) . And also, I didn't understand what you mean by "fetch the city..." , how exactly? I'm fairly new to .net and c# so sorry for the beginner questions

Comment: Fetch the city, means that when the ORM tool hits the query on the database, it will generate a join to take the data from city in the same query of the street. If you dont do that, it will execute a lazy loading to fetch the city's name.

Comment: Ok , so, how can I use the Entity framework to make this relations ? As I said, I created them in VS from scratch, though they already exists in the DB. So where do I specify the relations ? `city.id -> street.cityId`